# Trying to create a countdown that also reads hours seconds and minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is not all my work, i have borrowed alot of it as im new to coding and would rather try improve other code than start my own project yet
I am trying to have it read zero days and so many hours if the date inputted is tomorrows date. All in Python. I appreciate any help or pointers rather than just doing it for me.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import time

today = date.today()

def user_birthday():
    year = int(input('When is your birthday? [YY] '))
    month = int(input('When is your birthday? [MM] '))
    day = int(input('When is your birthday? [DD] '))

    birthday = datetime(year,month,day)
    return birthday

def hours_left(birthday):
    today == date.fromtimestamp(time.time() + 86400)
    birthday = date(today.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
    if birthday == today.day + 86400:
      birthday = birthday.replace(day = 1 - 1)
      return birthday
    dt = datetime
    now = dt.now()
    hour = 24 - (now.hour + 1)
    minute = 60 - now.minute
    second = 60 - now.second
    hts = str(hour) + " Hours", str(minute) + " Minutes", str(second) + " Seconds"
    return hts

def calculate_dates(birthday):
    today == date.fromtimestamp(time.time())
    birthday = date(today.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
    if birthday < today:
        birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year + 1)
        return birthday
    elif birthday == today:
      birthday = birthday.replace(day = 1 - 1)
      return birthday
    elif birthday == today:
        print("Happy Birthday!")
    else:
        return birthday
 
bday = user_birthday()
t = calculate_dates(bday)
time_to_birthday = t-today
days = str(time_to_birthday.days)
day = time_to_birthday
htss = str(hours_left)
print("Days until Your Birthday : " + days + " days and" + htss)
```

I have attempted multiple times to have it read 0 days through many methods. additionally have attempted to have the hours minutes and seconds print at the same ti,e but having issues.

Comment: Might want to use `hours_left(bday)` to call the function instead of outputting the function address.

Comment: Also, `calculate_dates` will return `None` if it's the user's birthday. I would recommend to just put one `return birthday` at the end of the function and remove the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I am not absolutely certain what your end goal might be but if I am following what you want correctly you are trying to:

1. Have the user input their birth date using the function `user_birthday`
2. Report the time in days and seconds until their next birthday.

The following code would seem to be a cleaner approach to getting what you want.

```
from datetime import datetime

def user_birthday():
    year = int(input('When is your birthday? [YY] '))
    month = int(input('When is your birthday? [MM] '))
    day = int(input('When is your birthday? [DD] '))
    return datetime(year,month,day)

def computeTimeDelta(bday):
    today = datetime.today()
    yr = today.year
    if today.month == bday.month:
        if today.day > bday.day:
            yr += 1
    elif today.month < today.month:
        yr += 1
    nxt_bday = datetime(yr, bday.month, bday.day)
    print(nxt_bday, bday, today)
    if today.year < yr :        
        return nxt_bday - today
    elif today.day < nxt_bday.day:
        return nxt_bday - today
    return today - nxt_bday

computeTimeDelta(user_birthday)
```

The result of running the `computeTimeDelta` is a
`datetime.timedelta(days=ddd, seconds=sss, microseconds=kkk)` which will produce the difference between today's date & time and the next occurrence of the entered birth date.  This may take some formatting to get into the exact format you need, but all important factors should be extractable from the result.